# How to snap line string start & end vertex to the nearest point?

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, spatial

I have a point layer and a line layer. The points are road junctions, collected using DGPS, while the lines are the connecting roads, collected through Handheld GPS in tracking mode. As a result, the lines are not actually connected to the points.

[image: Sample Network Image]

Now I want to:

1. Remove all intermediate nodes from each line string, to make it a straight line.
2. Snap the start & end vertex of lines to the nearest points.

I am using PostGIS 2.0.This by far what I have done:

```
UPDATE line
SET geom = ST_Simplify(geom, 1000);
```

Q. Is there any other better way to accomplish it?(Since I am using an absurd tolerance)

```
UPDATE line
SET geom = ST_AddPoint(
(SELECT geom FROM line WHERE id = 1),
(SELECT p.geom FROM point AS p, line AS l
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(p.geom,(SELECT ST_StartPoint(l.geom) FROM lt WHERE l.id=1)) LIMIT 1),
0)
WHERE id=1;
```

This will extend the line(with id=1) to the nearest point(point added at the beginning of the line).

Q. The above looks a bit complicated, is there any other efficient method/function available?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be reasonable to do both operations on the same query (not tested):

```
UPDATE line l
SET geom = ST_MakeLine(
    (SELECT geom FROM point p ORDER BY ST_Distance(p.geom, ST_StartPoint(l.geom)) LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT geom FROM point p ORDER BY ST_Distance(p.geom, ST_EndPoint(l.geom)) LIMIT 1)
);
```

If data set is small and you are running query only once, performance isn't issue - but you could add additional bbox comparision to speed things up:

```
SELECT geom FROM point p WHERE p.geom && ST_Expand(ST_StartPoint(l.geom), 100) ORDER BY ST_Distance(p.geom, ST_StartPoint(l.geom)) LIMIT 1
```